# ActionScript 3 - How do I pass content of TextArea to SharedObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to save the content (input by the user) of a `TextArea` field to a local SharedObject when the user clicks on a submit button. I am an absolute beginner with AS3, so I am probably asking a really stupid question but...where am I going wrong? At present this creates the file but it contains `"answertext answer[ans_field]"` and not the text entered into the field!

Any help would be much appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
import fl.controls.TextArea;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var ans_field: TextArea = new TextArea();
var MySO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("answertext");


sub_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f3_MouseClickHandler);

function f3_MouseClickHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
MySO.data.answer = "[ans_field]"
MySO.flush();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're after:

```
MySO.data.answer = ans_field.text;
```

[Read more about `TextField` and its `text` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#text).

Comment: Thank you very much! Something so simple :)